# How can I replace all spaces into a dash in a captured subexpression of regex in VB.NET?

Tags: regex, vb.net

Here is my code:

```
regExp = New Regex("\[def\](.+?)\[\/def\]")
strTextToReplace = regExp.Replace(strTextToReplace, "<a href=""/$1"">$1</a>")
```

I want to replace all spaces with a dash in "$1". How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a match evaluator:

```
Dim rx = New Regex("(?s)\[def](.+?)\[/def]")
Dim result = rx.Replace(s, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
         Return String.Format("<a href=""/{0}"">{0}</a>", m.Groups(1).Value.Replace(" ", "-"))
     End Function))
```

`m` is the *Match* object that is passed to the `Regex.Replace` method when a match occurs, and you replace all spaces with hyphens only in `.Groups(1)` (the first capturing group.

If you need to replace any whitespace with `-`, replace `m.Groups(1).Value.Replace(" ", "-")` with `Regex.Replace(m.Groups(1).Value, "\s", "-")`.